# How do I search text then print the result?

Tags: perl, search

I am searching for "o" then prints all lines with "o". Any suggestion/code I must apply?

data.txt:

```
j,o,b:
a,b,d:
o,l,e:
f,a,r:
e,x,o:
```

desired output:

```
j,o,b:
o,l,e:
e,x,o:
```

Comment: When you get your grade please update this question so we can all feel proud or ashamed.

Answer (score 9):

```
grep o data.txt

perl -ne 'print if (/o/);' <data.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have grep on your system, then `grep o data.txt` from the command line should do the trick.

Failing that, you could try Perl:

```
open IN, 'data.txt';
my @l = <IN>;
close IN;
foreach my $l (@l) {
   $l =~ /o/ and print $l;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep "o" data.txt
```

Does that help? I don't know Perl, but you can get the same output using the above grep.

Answer (score 1):

```
print if /o/;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Perl:

```
while (<>) { print if /o/; }
```

or with grep:

```
grep 'o' data.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

as a very short one-liner:

```
> perl -pe'$_ x=/o/' filename
```